# Python - Finding the top 5 rows containing a word in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a function that prints the top 5 products and their prices, and the bottom 5 products and their prices of the product listings that contain words from a wordlist. I've tried making it like this -

```
def wordlist_top_costs(filename, wordlist):
    xlsfile = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    dframe = xlsfile.parse('Sheet1')    
    dframe['Product'].fillna('', inplace=True)
    dframe['Price'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    price = {}
    for word in wordlist:
        mask = dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False, na=False)
        price[mask] = dframe.loc[mask, 'Price']

    top = sorted(Score.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    print("Top 10 product prices for: ", wordlist.name)
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print(top[i][0], "  |  ", t[i][1])  

    bottom = sorted(Score.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=False)
    print("Bottom 10 product prices for: ", wordlist.name)
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print(top[i][0], "  |  ", t[i][1])
```

However, the above function throws an error at line 
`price[mask] = dframe.loc[mask, 'Price in AUD']` that says -
`TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`
Any help to correct/modify this appreciated. Thanks!

Edit -
For eg.
wordlist - alu, co, vin

Product | Price

- Aluminium Crown - 22.20
- Coca Cola - 1.0
- Brass Box - 28.75
- Vincent Kettle - 12.00
- Vinyl Stickers - 0.50
- Doritos - 2.0
- Colin's Hair Oil - 5.0
- Vincent Chase Sunglasses - 75.40
- American Tourister - $120.90

Output :

Top 3 Product Prices:

Vincent Chase Sunglasses - 75.40

Aluminium Crown - 22.20

Vincent Kettle - 12.0

Bottom 3 Product Prices:

Vinyl Stickers - 0.50

Coca Cola - 1.0

Colin's Hair Oil - 5.0

Comment: Can you add some data sample, 10 rows e.g. for top3?

Comment: You are keeping dictionary key as Series which is mutable. Dictionary can have only immutable keys. price[mask] = dframe.lock[mask,'Price'] - this line is wrong. mask is series which is mutable data structure. Use something else as key of dictionary.

Comment: @SunnysinhSolanki something else like? Can I do this without using dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) and 
[`nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html):

```
#remove $ and convert column Price to floats
dframe['Price'] = dframe['Price'].str.replace('$', '').astype(float)

#filter by regex - joined all values of list by |
wordlist = ['alu', 'co', 'vin'] 
pat = '|'.join(wordlist)
mask = dframe.Product.str.contains(pat, case=False, na=False)
dframe = dframe.loc[mask, ['Product','Price']]

top = dframe.nlargest(3, 'Price')
#top = dframe.sort_values('Price', ascending=False).head(3)
print (top)
                    Product  Price
7  Vincent Chase Sunglasses   75.4
0           Aluminium Crown   22.2
3            Vincent Kettle   12.0

bottom = dframe.nsmallest(3, 'Price')
#bottom = dframe.sort_values('Price').head(3)
print (bottom)
            Product  Price
4    Vinyl Stickers    0.5
1         Coca Cola    1.0
6  Colin's Hair Oil    5.0
```

**Setup**:

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame({'Price': ['22.20', '1.0', '28.75', '12.00', '0.50', '2.0', '5.0', '75.40', '$120.90'], 'Product': ['Aluminium Crown', 'Coca Cola', 'Brass Box', 'Vincent Kettle', 'Vinyl Stickers', 'Doritos', "Colin's Hair Oil", 'Vincent Chase Sunglasses', 'American Tourister']}, columns=['Product','Price'])
print (dframe)
                    Product    Price
0           Aluminium Crown    22.20
1                 Coca Cola      1.0
2                 Brass Box    28.75
3            Vincent Kettle    12.00
4            Vinyl Stickers     0.50
5                   Doritos      2.0
6          Colin's Hair Oil      5.0
7  Vincent Chase Sunglasses    75.40
8        American Tourister  $120.90
```

Comment: Awesome! That works well. However, I only want 2 columns of the dataframe - `Product` and `Price`. How to do that?

Comment: You can change `dframe = dframe[mask]` to `dframe = dframe[mask, ['Product','Price']]`

Comment: That didn't work! Gives me the error - `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: @harry04 - I add sample data to answer, problem is with filtering? Or something else?

Comment: Yeah, it's in the line - `dframe = dframe[mask, ['Product','Price in AUD']]`

Comment: Yes - `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I forget for loc, sorry. `dframe = dframe.loc[mask, ['Product','Price']]` now tested, it working nice.

Comment: Oh yeah! I forgot that too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For one of the datasets, the line of code - `top = dframe.nlargest(15, 'Price in AUD')` throws the error - `TypeError: Column 'Price' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nlargest' with this dtype`. What can I do to filter this out?

Comment: It means there are no numbers. E.g. there are `$`, so need `dframe['Price'] = dframe['Price'].str.replace('$', '').astype(float)` for remove `$` and cast to `float`. Is possible check what is problematic value?